# Can you simplify XML Arrays?

Tags: arrays, xml

I want to create an XML "database" that currently looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfSport xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <sport name="football">
    <countries>
      <country name="england">
        <leagues>
          <league name="premierleague">
            <teams>
              <team key="man" value="Manchester United" />
              <team key="arse" value="Arsenal" />
              <team key="bour" value="Bournemouth" />
            </teams>
          </league>
        </leagues>
      </country>
    </countries>
  </sport>
</ArrayOfSport>
```

As you can see, this XML can be very messy. So, my question is, can you simplify XML Arrays (`<countries>`, `<leagues>`, `<teams>`) like in the example above into something like this?:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfSport xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <sport name="football">
    <country name="england">
      <league name="premierleague">
        <team key="man" value="Manchester United" />
        <team key="arse" value="Arsenal" />
        <team key="bour" value="Bournemouth" />
      </league>
    </country>
  </sport>
</ArrayOfSport>
```

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693072.aspx#Anchor_2).

Here's the C# code that generated the valid XML:

```
var sports =
    new XElement("sports",
        new XElement("sport", new XAttribute("name", "football"),
            new XElement("country", new XAttribute("name", "england"),
                new XElement("league", new XAttribute("name", "premierleague"),
                    new XElement("team", new XAttribute("key", "man"), new XAttribute("value", "Manchester United")),
                    new XElement("team", new XAttribute("key", "arse"), new XAttribute("value", "Arsenal")),
                    new XElement("team", new XAttribute("key", "bour"), new XAttribute("value", "Bournemouth"))
                )
            )
        )
    );

using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\XElementTest.xml", FileMode.Create))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
{
    writer.Write(sports);
}
```

It generated this XML:

```
<sports>
  <sport name="football">
    <country name="england">
      <league name="premierleague">
        <team key="man" value="Manchester United" />
        <team key="arse" value="Arsenal" />
        <team key="bour" value="Bournemouth" />
      </league>
    </country>
  </sport>
</sports>
```